# MongoDB how to count array elements with Java driver

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I need my application to count the size of an array `foos` inside a document using Java driver 3.8. I know I can do this with the shell

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $match: { _id: 123456789 }
      },
      {
         $project: {
            count: { $size: "$foos" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

but I have no idea of how to do this with java, because the only method producing a `$size` operator I found is `Filters.size(String fieldName, int size)` that is meant to look for documents where array `fieldName` has size `size`. I searched inside com.mongodb.client.model package but I found nothing to answer my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there are no helpers in java driver to help with aggregation expression for `$project` stage.

Try

```
Bson match = new Document("$match", Filters.eq("_id", 123456789 ));
Bson projection = new Document("$size", "$foos" );
Bson project = Aggregates.project(new Document("count", projection) );
collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, project));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field and put the size of the array inside it and use it for count or sorting.

**use "addFields" java Helper**

```
addFields(new Field("productsCount",
            new Document("$size", "$products")));
```

Where

1. '**productsCount**' is the name of the new field
2. '**products**' is the Array
3. '**$size**' is the MongoDB aggregation.

Comment: Then you have to maintain this field.  Saving calculations is almost never a good idea.  (Notable exception being long calculations)  It's better to calculate in memory.